# How to override a specific signing algorithm in a Java SSL Context

Tags: java, security, ssl

How can I override a specific signing algorithm in a Java SSL Context and use my own implementation of say SHA256withRSA.
I have tried

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new MYprovider(), 1);
SSLContext sslC = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslC.init(mykeyManagers, mytrustManagers, null);
```

But the set provider is always SunJSSE and my implementation in MYprovider is never used.
If I remove SunJSSE first, i.e Security.removeProvider("SunJSSE"); Security.insertProviderAt(new MYprovider(), 1); this would be ok .. but then I would need to implement many more methods than I really want to.

Also according to the documentation the SunJSSE provider uses the SunJCE implementation for all its cryptographic needs. However I don't seem able to get my implementation of say SHA256withRSA to be chosen before the SUNJCE providers implementations. Removing the SUNJCE provider just means that all the remaining crypto algorithms necessary would become unavailable (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No negotiable cipher suite)

Comment: What algorithms does your provider register? Are you sure your provider is used all? because if I remember correctly security providers have to be signed, otherwise they are ignored.

Comment: The algorithms are SHAxxRSA.  These I can use OK in other Java applications. The problem lies when I want to do TLS with the JSSE and I want it to use my implementation instead of its own (or other).
As for code signing ..only Providers that provide implementations for encryption services (Cipher, KeyAgreement.) must be digitally signed by a certificate issued by a trusted CA  and here  I am only interested in signing algorithms (also openjdk does not seem to even bother with this restriction). Of course the JSSE implementation may do some sort of checking .. but I don’t know.

Comment: So you have registered your algorithm the same way as it is registered in [SunJSSE](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SunJSSE.java) (also the OIDs and so on)?

Comment: yes. I believe so.